# StackOverflowException in EntityFramework.dll when fetching large amount of records from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am facing a problem with entity framework. I am reciving an array of ints, and than I fetch these records from database using this code.

```
var items = _context.Items.Where(a => listOfInts.Any(b => b == a.ID)).ToList();
```

This code works fine, when listOfInts does not exceed about 1000 ids.
When it does, then stack overflow exception is being thrown.

How can I change my code to get rid of this error?

Comment: You're probably better off using `Contains` instead of `Any`, but given you want more than 1000 entries in the list, this looks like it's not a good way to extract data anyway.

Comment: So there is no hope for me?

Comment: I think that the problem is that you force this code to a list by using `.ToList()`.

Comment: you probably want to move to a raw sql statement or Dapper

Comment: u can take a look for sql profile, see how EF transfer your query to sql query, and after that try add index or any improve for performance.

Comment: @RonaldHaan No, that won't cause a `StackOverflowException`, whatever happens, the data needs to be materialised, whether you use a `ToList` or just loop over the queryable, that error will still happen.

Comment: @justme There is hope, but not for your current method. One option is to store those values in the database an join to your `Items` table. The eliminates any need for passing around parameters (note SQL Server will throw an error if you pass over ~2000 parameters)

Comment: @DavidG writing these ids to temp table and than joining them to the items table does not sound like a good idea. It may cause another problems with concurrency and so on. This is really simple operation - fetching data. I do hope that it may be solved other way.

Comment: Is `listOfInts` actually `List<int>`?

Comment: Instead of using `ToList()` you can get with chunks of 100 items or whatever you want to have like `.Skip(0).Take(100)`. You can iterate it until you fetched all of them. Please keep it in mind that all data will be stored in memory and that can be a bit problem.

Comment: @omerfaruk how storing 2k records in memory these days may cause problem?

Comment: @tia yes it is.

Comment: @justme even though memories are great that doesn't mean that we should store everything in there. It will work cumulative at the end so if i were dealing with this scenario i would probably go for chunks implementation.